# Jackson - Serialize ZonedDateTime to ISO 8601 String

Tags: java, datetime, serialization, jackson

I want to serialize a `ZonedDateTime` to an **ISO 8601** compliant String, e.g.:
`2018-02-14T01:01:02.074+0100`.

I tried the following:

```
@JsonProperty("@timestamp")
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
```

But unfortunately it does not give the correct result and serializes the `ZonedDateTime` with all its fields, etc.

Thank you already for your help!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure you include and register the Jackson module for date and time classes introduced in Java 8. E.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.10</version>
</dependency>
```

and if necessary:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Side note: You may also achieve the desired format without the annotation and just configuring `ObjectMapper` to not serialize date as timestamp. E.g.

```
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Comment: I tried this without success.

Even tried:  mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false); - no joy.

Comment: For anyone refactoring a Spring MVC project into a Spring Boot Web application, make sure you don't have an `@Configuration` class annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`!  This was causing Spring MVC to load and ignore our Spring Boot configuration.

Comment: Using current java at time of commenting, I didn't need to add jackson-datatype-jsr310 to the pom.  I do have javax.ws.rs-api and jersey-media-json-jackson however, so maybe it's a sub-dependency of one of those?